# Payara Server 5 Community version #badassfish message on webpage fail

Tags: payara

Anyone know how I can remove or change the message the user sees when a webpage fails. Currently it shows the error message plus "#badassfish", which I do not want the customer to see. I would prefer to change that or remove it. In D:\payara5\glassfish\config\branding\glassfish-version.properties I found the #badassfish in a line identifying it as a version_suffix. Does anyone know if I can change or delete #badassfish? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the #badassfish from the version.properties file, which will remove it from the error pages.

Additionally you can create a custom error page and set it to be using the web.xml file, i.e.:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/Error404</location>
</error-page>
```

Which will use the resource at that endpoint if the user encounters an error.